# Basic SQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm new to MySQL, so I'm confused on what the correct syntax is to answer these questions. The schema is as follows:

```
Product (maker, model, type)
PC (model, speed, ram, hdisk, price)
Laptop (model, speed, ram, hdisk, screen, price)
Printer (model, color, type, price)
```

1. When updating the RAM or hard disk of any PC, check that the updated PC has at least 100 times as much hard disk as RAM.
2. When inserting a new PC, laptop, or printer, make sure that the model number did not previously appear in any of `PC`, `Laptop`, or `Printer`.

Comment: Please add the query you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your question, I am assuming you're new to SQL/MySql.

Although you're on right track here. You need SQL Triggers to achieve the mentioned task.

**Note:** Please try the task by yourself and If you stuck somewhere then only go 
through the below answer.

Task 1: Obviously it requires an `Update trigger` on table `PC`. The trigger will be executed on each update on `PC`.

But, following is an statement from Mysql Documentation ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)):

> A BEFORE trigger is activated by the attempt to insert or modify the
>   row, regardless of whether the attempt subsequently succeeds.

So, even if we create an trigger and show error message, updation may still take place on `PC`.

To prevent the updation process, we'll use `SQLState` inside Trigger.

There are unique `SQLState` or `Signal` for each failures in MySql and we'll set relevant `SQLState` to prevent update on `PC`.

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER BF_UPD_PC
     BEFORE UPDATE ON PC  FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.hdisk >= 100*(NEW.ram) 
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: HardDisk should be at least 100 times more than RAM.';
          END IF;
     END;
```

**Task 2:**

Here, we need to create a `Before Insert` trigger that can verify that the new model number is not already assigned to any `PC`,`Printer` or `Laptop` as it supposed to be unique.

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER BF_INS_PRODUCT
     BEFORE INSERT ON PRODUCT
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.model in (select distinct model from pc
                           union all
                           select distinct model from printer
                           union all
                           select distinct model from laptop)
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: Model number already assigned. Please try with another model number';
          END IF;
     END;
```

Done!

Hope it helps!